# C++ stateful allocator de-allocate issues

Tags: c++11, memory-management, allocator

This issue is my misunderstanding of how the standard is using my custom allocator. I have a stateful allocator that keeps a vector of allocated blocks. This vector is pushed into when allocating and searched through during de-allocation.

From my debugging it appears that different instances of my object (this*'s differ) are being called on de-allocation. An example may be that MyAllocator (this* = 1) is called to allocate 20 bytes, then some time later MyAllocator (this* = 2) is called to de-allocate the 20 bytes allocated earlier. Abviously the vector in MyAllocator (this* = 2) doesn't contain the 20 byte block allocated by the other allocator so it fails to de-allocate. My understanding was that C++11 allows stateful allocators, what's going on and how do i fix this?

I already have my operator == set to only return true when this == &rhs

pseudo-code:

```
template<typename T>
class MyAllocator
{
    ptr allocate(int n)
    {
       ...make a block of size sizeof(T) * n
       blocks.push_back(block);
       return (ptr)block.start;
    }

    deallocate(ptr start, int n)
    {
        /*This fails because the the block array is not the
        same and so doesn't find the block it wants*/ 
        std::erase(std::remove_if(blocks.begin,blocks.end, []()
        {
            return block.start >= (uint64_t)ptr && block.end <= ((uint64_t)ptr + sizeof(T)*n);
        }), blocks.end);
    }

    bool operator==(const MyAllocator& rhs)
    {
        //my attempt to make sure internal states are same
        return this == &rhs;
    }
private:
  std::vector<MemoryBlocks> blocks;
}
```

Im using this allocator for an std::vector, on gcc. So as far as i know no weird rebind stuff is going on

Comment: An allocator must be copyable. A typical approach to a stateful allocator is to have lightweight copyable proxies that forward to an object they share, which maintains state and does the actual work.

Comment: This should be copyable no? The default copy constructor of this allocator should copy the state (vector of blocks) and then we'd have two identical allocators. It appears to me that the vector that's using my allocator is using an 'old' copy?

Comment: Yes, your allocator is copyable - but copies don't share state. Each has its own independent list of blocks, and doesn't know about blocks allocated by the other. By the way, now that you point out your `operator==` implementation, your class violates [allocator requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator): a copy of an allocator must compare equal to the original, but yours doesn't. (You are also missing `operator!=`). So it's not even an allocator class in the first place.

Comment: Oh i didn't realize copies had to share state past the time they are copied. That's what i was missing, thank you. I do have operator!= in my code, it just removed it for brevity. This requirement adds an interesting complication.

Comment: In the simplest case, allocate `blocks` on the heap and manage it by `shared_ptr`. The rest should mostly just work, I think.

Comment: In this particular case it's fairly complex because i'm actually manually walking the memory pages, allocating a page, splitting the page into 'blocks' , and managing which blocks belong to which pages. But you've told me the missing info so i can do it now, thanks. If you want to post your comment as an answer i will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Igor mentioned, allocators must be copyable. Importantly though they must share their state between copies, even AFTER they have been copied from. In this case the fix was easy, i made the blocks vector a shared_ptr as suggested and then now on copy all the updates to that vector occur to the same vector, since they all point to the same thing.