# Crash when try to write a custom allocate_shared allocator and make it thread_local

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory, allocator

My program has several type of small objects to be created and destroyed very frequently in each thread using make_shared, and the shared_ptr will not be passed to another thread, in which case, I decide to write a custom allocate_shared allocator with a boost::pool as its member to allocate fixed size of memory according to the type.

My code is as follows:

ObjectAllocator.h:

```
#include <boost/pool/pool.hpp>

template<typename T>
class ObjectAllocator
{
public:
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef T value_type;

    auto static constexpr block_size=64+sizeof(value_type);

public:
    ObjectAllocator() noexcept:pool_(block_size){}
    ObjectAllocator(const ObjectAllocator &other) noexcept :pool_(block_size){}
    ~ObjectAllocator()=default;

    template<typename U>
    ObjectAllocator(const ObjectAllocator<U> &other) noexcept :pool_(block_size){}

    template<typename U>
    ObjectAllocator& operator= (const ObjectAllocator<U> &other){
        return *this;
    }

    ObjectAllocator<T>& operator = (const ObjectAllocator &other){
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename U>
    struct rebind{ typedef ObjectAllocator<U> other; };

    T *allocate(size_type n, const void *hint=nullptr){
#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(n==1);
#endif
        return static_cast<T*>(pool_.malloc());
    }

    void deallocate(T *ptr, size_type n){
#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(n==1);
#endif
        pool_.free(ptr);
    }

private:
    boost::pool<> ObjectAllocator<T>::pool_(block_size);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator == (const ObjectAllocator<T>&, const ObjectAllocator<U>&){
    return true;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator != (const ObjectAllocator<T>& a, const ObjectAllocator<U> &b){
    return !(a==b);
}


namespace Allocator {
template <typename T>
thread_local ObjectAllocator<T> allocator;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
class ObjectA{
public:
    int s=0;
    void func(){
        std::cout<<s<<std::endl;
    }
    ObjectA() {//std::cout<<"()"<<std::endl;}
    ~ObjectA() {//std::cout<<"~"<<std::endl;}
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ObjectA>> vec;
void test(){
    static uint32_t loop_count=1000*1000;
    for(uint32_t i=0;i<loop_count;i++){
         shared_ptr<ObjectA> packet = allocate_shared<ObjectA, ObjectAllocator<ObjectA>>(Allocator::allocator<ObjectA>);
         vec.push_back(packet);
    }
    vec.clear();
}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ObjectA>> vec2;
void test2(){
    static uint32_t loop_count=1000*1000;
    for(uint32_t i=0;i<loop_count;i++){
        shared_ptr<ObjectA> packet = allocate_shared<ObjectA, ObjectAllocator<ObjectA>>(Allocator::allocator<ObjectA>);
        vec2.push_back(packet);
    }
    vec2.clear();
}

int main() {
    std::thread thread1(test);
    test2();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to test it, it crashs and I have no idea why.
Could anyone helps to make it correct? Thanks in advance.

The debugger says seg fault in shared_ptr_base.h

> void*    _M_get_deleter(const std::type_info& __ti) const noexcept  { return _M_pi ? _M_pi->_M_get_deleter(__ti) : nullptr; }

When I try to make boost::pool static, it works fine in single thread and crashes in multi-thread
The debugger says seg fault in shared_ptr_base.h

> : _M_use_count(1), _M_weak_count(1) { }

---

update:
I make boost::pool to be static thread_local and it works properly now

```
template<typename T>
class ObjectAllocator
{
public:
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef T value_type;

    auto static constexpr block_size=64+sizeof(value_type);

public:
    ObjectAllocator() noexcept{}
    ObjectAllocator(const ObjectAllocator &other) noexcept {}
    ~ObjectAllocator()=default;

    template<typename U>
    ObjectAllocator(const ObjectAllocator<U> &other) noexcept {}

    template<typename U>
    ObjectAllocator& operator= (const ObjectAllocator<U> &other){
        return *this;
    }

    ObjectAllocator<T>& operator = (const ObjectAllocator &other){
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename U>
    struct rebind{ typedef ObjectAllocator<U> other; };

    T *allocate(size_type n, const void *hint=nullptr){
#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(n==1);
#endif
        return static_cast<T*>(pool_.malloc());
    }

    void deallocate(T *ptr, size_type n){
#ifdef _DEBUG
        assert(n==1);
#endif
        pool_.free(ptr);
    }

private:
    thread_local static boost::pool<> pool_;
};

template<typename T>
thread_local boost::pool<> ObjectAllocator<T>::pool_(block_size);


template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator == (const ObjectAllocator<T>&, const ObjectAllocator<U>&){
    return true;
}

template<typename T, typename U>
inline bool operator != (const ObjectAllocator<T>& a, const ObjectAllocator<U> &b){
    return !(a==b);
}

namespace Allocator {
template <typename T>
thread_local static ObjectAllocator<T> allocator;
}

template <typename T, typename ...Args>
inline auto custom_make_shared(Args... args){
    return std::allocate_shared<T,ObjectAllocator<T>>(Allocator::allocator<T>,std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the execution using a debugger to find out *where* it crashes?

Comment: @UnholySheep  I have added the debug info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your copy constructors for `ObjectAllocator` create a new instance of `boost::pool` each time they're called.

As `std::allocate_shared` copies the allocator ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared)), the instance of `ObjectAllocator` used to allocate `std::shared_ptr` gets destructed with it's pool before the `shared_ptr` is destroyed.

Related question: [C++ stateful allocator de-allocate issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44739042/c-stateful-allocator-de-allocate-issues)

Probably unrelated to you problem, but there are also few other issues:

- you don't join `thread1` in `main`. This will call `std::terminate` and crash you program.
- `boost::pool<> ObjectAllocator<T>::pool_(block_size);` - the `ObjectAllocator<T>::` part is superfluous and nonstandard. (afaik accepted only in MSVC)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After reading the doc you mentioned, I realized I misunderstood some key points in how stl use my allocator. I make some small adjustment to my code and it works now. By the way, the ObjectAllocator<T>::  is accepted in my gcc compiler, if its not standard, could you please tell me the standard way to write this?